# ある条件下でのみif文に含まれる処理をすべて実行したい

Tags: c#

私は C# の初心者です。この質問は初歩的なものですが、私にとっては難しいです。

if 文を使用して条件分岐を実行しています。 しかし、ある条件下で、そのif文に含まれる処理をすべて実行したいと考えています。
私のプログラムには if 文がたくさんありますが、これは賢い書き方とは思えません。
「a」の記述が冗長なので、どちらかの if 文に「a」の条件を入れ忘れる可能性があります。

処理Bと処理Cを重複させずに、「a」の場合のすべての処理を実行する賢い方法はありますか？

```
if (a || b)
{
    Process B
}
if (a || c)
{
    Process C
}
if (a || d)
{
    Process D
}
```

Comment: 私には文意を汲み取ることが難しいのですが、[こういう事](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yXTR83) でしょうか？

Comment: どういう条件なのかコードでなく言葉で書けませんか？ 質問のコードは質問者さんのやりたいことと違うように思われますので。

Comment: WebSurfer さんのコメントをもう少し説明しますと、質問のコードは処理が `else if` でつながっていますので、最初に真になった処理のみが実行されます。
つまり、`a` が真である場合は最初の処理 `Process B` のみが実行されます。
これが「ある条件下で、そのif文に含まれる処理をすべて実行したい」という文章と矛盾している、ということです。
私は、文章を優先して回答いたしました。

Comment: 説明のための簡略化された疑似コードなのかもしれませんが、各変数の値がどのような組み合わせで取りうるのかも条件として書かれていた方が良さそうです。

Comment: 失礼しました。サンプルとして記載したコードを誤ってif～else ifでつなげてしまいました。ご指摘のように本来は全てif文となっています。
実際にやりたいことは大量のチェックボックスに対して、例えばbチェックボックスのチェック状態をfalseに変更した場合、x/yチェックボックスのEnabledをfalseにするようなことを「Process B」として記載しています。ただ、特定の条件下ではその処理（Process BやProcess C）を全て実行したい、というものでした。

Comment: 回答のコメントに「本件クローズとさせてください」とありますが、これを質問文にも追記してください。

Comment: @metropolis このサイトでは、質問者さんが希望しても「クローズ」にはしません。このままで大丈夫です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

配列などのデータ構造にまとめて扱うのが良いと思います。

例:

```csharp
// 私はC#ユーザーでは無いので、これは慣用的なC#コードではないかも知れません

var a = false;
var b = true;
var c = true;
var d = true;

// 条件（ブール値）と処理内容（関数）のタプルを要素に持つ配列
var processes = new (bool,  Action)[] {
    (b, () => Console.WriteLine("Process B")),
    (c, () => Console.WriteLine("Process C")),
    (d, () => Console.WriteLine("Process D")),
};


if (a) {
    // 全ての処理を実行
    // 条件部は利用しないので「_」で捨てる
    foreach (var (_, func) in processes) {
        func();
    }
} else {
    // 条件部が真である処理を実行する
    foreach (var (cond, func) in processes) {
        if (cond) {
            func();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `processes`を定義した時点でb,c,dが評価される(定義した後にb,c,dが変化しても影響されない)ことに注意が必要です

Comment: そうならば`a`～`d`の方も値ではなく関数/lambda/delegate等にして、呼び出して判定すれば良いのかもしれません。

Comment: @mjy♦ 
ありがとうございます。私の知識では実際にやってみないとこの方法でやりたいことが実現できるか確証が持てないものの、言わんとされていることはイメージできました。本件、残念ながら私のポイント不足（？）で+評価がつけられないのですが、本件クローズとさせてください。

Comment: @okaken このサイトでは、質問者さんが満足しても、回答の受け付けを締め切ることはありません。
ですから、「クローズ」などの必要はありません。
回答に対する対応は、[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) をご覧下さい（よく解らなければ、何もしなくても大丈夫です）。

Answer (score 2):

> 「a」の記述が冗長なので、どちらかの if 文に「a」の条件を入れ忘れる可能性があります。

解決すべき課題が何なのかいまいちわからないのですが，
問題視しているのが「冗長さ」ではなくて「書き忘れる可能性」なのだということであれば……

```
//各処理を　使う情報を引数に取る　メソッドにする．
void ProcessB( bool a, bool b ){ ... }
void ProcessC( bool a, bool c ){ ... }
void ProcessD( bool a, bool d ){ ... }

//呼ぶ側
void SomeFunc()
{
  //必ず引数を２つ指定しないとコンパイル通らないから「書き忘れ」は無い．
  //（「書き間違い」ならばあり得るだろうけども）
  ProcessB( a, b );
  ProcessC( a, c );
  ProcessD( a, d );
}
```

のように，明示的に「 `a` と `b` を引数とするメソッド」といった形に書けばどうですか？
さすがにこの状態で `{...}` の箇所の実装時に「`a` の存在を忘れて（というか無視して） `b` だけ使うコードを書いちゃう」ということはそうそう無いのではないか，と思います．

Answer (score 0):

条件aのケースで条件bcdを判定するという意味ですか？

```
if(a)
{
    if (b)
    {
        Process B
    }
    else if (c)
    {
        Process C
    }
    else if (d)
    {
        Process D
    }

}
```

補足を受けて条件aの適合時に全てのプロセスを実行する処理を試作しました
バージョン指定がないのでC#10.0以降を前提としています

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

Random random = new Random();
Func<Random,int> result = static rand => rand.Next(2);
int a = result(random);

(bool,Delegate) b = (result(random) > 0,(string s) => WriteLine($"{s}:ProcessA")),
c = (result(random) > 0,(string s) => WriteLine($"{s}:ProcessB")),
d = (result(random) > 0,(string s) => WriteLine($"{s}:ProcessC"));

foreach((bool,Action<string>) p in new[]{b,c,d})
    if(p.Item1 && a > 0)
    {
        p.Item2("True");
        break;
    }
    else if(a == 0)
        p.Item2("False");
```

以上のコードは`result(Random rand)`が0か1のいずれを返すかで条件分岐を行う手続きです
タプル型の`(bool,Delegate)`で条件とそれに付随する処理(ラムダ式)をまとめておくことで、foreach内にて条件分岐によるプロセスの実行を管理します

例えば条件aを**int型の変数aが0のケース**と仮定すれば、この条件が成立する場合に`if(a == 0)`へ分岐して変数bcdのラムダメソッドを全て実行します

ここでは`if(p.Item1 && a > 0)`とのプロセスの競合がないことを分かりやすく示すために**True**もしくは**False**を文字列として受け取る引数を用意しています

条件が不成立の時は変数bcdの内最初にtrue判定となった変数のラムダメソッドだけを実行後`break`よりループを脱します

これで条件aの成立時にのみ全てのプロセスを実行するパターンを一応は構築できるかと思います

Comment: ありがとうございます。ただ、この書き方だとaでない場合、具体的にはbのみではProcess Bに到達せず、私がやりたことは実現できなさそうです。